# How to add image to Email behaviour

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know how to add `image` to the behaviour, actually i am trying to write the email behaviour where i am capable of changing the entry background but along with that i would like to add an image for it.

My xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
      <Entry Placeholder="Enter a System.Double">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
              <local:CustomBehavior />
          </Entry.Behaviors>
      </Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

My Behaviour class:

```
public class CustomBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
{
    private const string digitRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Entry entry;
        bool isValid;
        entry =(Entry)sender;
        isValid = Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, digitRegex);
        entry.BackgroundColor = isValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use an email icon, you could use an emoji, in other case you have to create a custom control with its own view

Comment: I wanted to add tick mark image when entered text is true and cross mark when the text in out of format.Could u paste a sample code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st.** For your request you have to add a separate Image to your layout, in your case:

```
<StackLayout
      Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Entry Placeholder="Enter a System.Double">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
              <local:CustomBehavior x:Name="customValidator"/>
          </Entry.Behaviors>
      </Entry>
      <Image
          HeightRequest="24"
          WidthRequest="24"
          Aspect="AspectFit"
          IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference customValidator},
                        Path=IsVisible}"
          Style="{Binding Source={x:Reference customValidator},
                        Path=IsValid,
                        Converter={StaticResource boolToStyleImage}}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Pay attention to the x:Name="" attribute as that is necessary to be able to reference that custom behavior within this xaml file

**2nd.** Create BindableProperties on your 'CustomBehavior' for two fields on which you'll bind the status of your image for your entry

```
public class CustomBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
{
    private const string digitRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
        @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

    static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly ("IsValid", typeof (bool), typeof (CustomBehavior), false);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

    static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsVisiblePropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly ("IsVisible", typeof (bool), typeof (CustomBehavior), false);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = IsVisiblePropertyKey.BindableProperty;

    private const string FRIEND = "friend";
    private const string FRIENDS = "friends";

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue (IsValidProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue (IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue (IsVisibleProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue (IsVisiblePropertyKey, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewTextValue.Length > 0)
        {
            IsVisible = true;
            Entry entry =(Entry)sender;
            IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, digitRegex);

            if(IsValid) // Check only if we have a valid email
            {
                // Here we validate if the email contains our requirements
                String email = entry.Text;
                int pos = email.IndexOf("@"); // Exclude the domain
                string username = email.Substring(0, pos);
                if(username.Contains(FRIEND) || username.Contains(FRIENDS))
                {
                    IsValid = true;
                }else
                    IsValid = false;
                }
            }
        }else
            IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

**3d.**  Create a simple ValueConverter class which will convert a boolean value to one of our objects of type 'T' depending on what we'll append this converter to.

```
namespace YourApp
public class BooleanToObjectConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T FalseObject { set; get; }

    public T TrueObject { set; get; }

    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? this.TrueObject : this.FalseObject;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((T)value).Equals (this.TrueObject);
    }
}
```

**4th.**  Add this style to ResourceDictionary tag on your App.xaml file which will declare the TrueObject(Style for a valid email) and the FalseObject(Style for an invalid email).

Replace "your_wrong_image_here.png" and "your_correct_image_here.png" to your desired images

```
<Application 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="YourApp.App"
    xmlns:statics="clr-namespace:YourApp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <statics:BooleanToObjectConverter x:Key="boolToStyleImage" 
x:TypeArguments="Style">
            <statics:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Property="Source" 
Value="your_wrong_image_here.png" />
                </Style>
            </statics:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>

            <statics:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Property="Source" 
Value="your_correct_image_here.png" />
                </Style>
            </statics:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
       </statics:BooleanToObjectConverter>
       </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This should fulfill your needs, just be careful from copy-paste errors as you have different class names on your project!

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.

Comment: @sahithi you're welcome, if it helped you please select as a correct answer

Comment: Thank you @ MalokuS,your answer works perfectly for me.Will you help me  to know how to compare a specific string in the email entry,for example every entry must and should contain "friend" or "friends" with general mail address like abc.friend@xyz.com or abc.friends@xyz.com.

Comment: Once more you're welcome @sahithi , glad it worked for you. Check the edit I made on your 'CustomBehavior' class with the new check.